# node js automatically pull data from text files which are in folders

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, file, directory

I'm  a new in nodejs. I need pull data from text file for example into array of objects. I have folder `/Motobike` which contains 4 sub-folders: `Sport`, `Cross`, `Cruiser`, `Chopper`

Each this folder contain 3 sub-folders: `New`, `Used`, `Re-manufactured`.

Each this folder contain 3 text files: `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` *(which are rating of motobikes)* and each file contain a name of motobike *(Honda, Yamaha, etc)* and a price *(1000, 1500, 3000, etc)*.

### ~/MotoBike

1. Sport

   - New

     - 1.txt
     - 2.txt
     - 3.txt
   - Used

     - 1.txt
     - 2.txt
     - 3.txt
   - Re-manufactured

     - 1.txt
     - 2.txt
     - 3.txt
2. Cross
3. Cruiser
4. Chopper

## sample txt file

```
Honda:3400 
Yamaha:3000 
Kawasaki:2800 
Suzuki:2750
```

I would like, that my application automatically pull data from text files into array of object. Thank you for help.

Comment: this a Q&A site and not a place for you to get your work done totally, you should be trying it yourself first and asks questions if needed

Comment: @ysytnik can you add a sample of what the `.txt` file contents look like

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal   Honda:3400
                                      Yamaha:3000
                                      Kawasaki:2800
                                      Suzuki:2750

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will help is to use JSON files instead of TXT. Javascript has methods for easily extracting data from JSON

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could get the data from the files as objects in an array. I provided a sample object of the end result and some sample code you could mess with.

## sample object

```
[{
  bike: 'Chopper',
  type: 'New',
  data: {
    Honda: 3400,
    Yamaha: 3000,
    Kawasaki: 2800,
    Suzuki: 2750
  }
}]
```

## sample code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const bikePaths = ["Chopper", "Cross", "Cruiser", "Sports"];
const bikeTypes = ["New", "Re-manufactured", "Used"];

function getFileAsObject(file, result) {

  let typeDir = path.dirname(file);
  let bikeDir = path.dirname(typeDir);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err)
        reject(err);

      let lines = data.split('\n').filter(line => line != '');

      let obj = lines.reduce((acc, line) => {
        let [key, value] = line.split(':');

        Object.assign(acc, {
          [key]: value
        })

        return acc;
      }, {});

      resolve({
        bike: path.basename(bikeDir),
        type: path.basename(typeDir),
        data: obj
      })
    })
  });
}



function readMotoBike(bikepaths, biketypes, result) {

  const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val), []);

  let allPaths = bikepaths.map(bike => biketypes.map(type => {
    let currpath = bike + "/" + type;

    let pathToFile = path.format({
      root: './MotoBike/',
      base: currpath
    });

    let allFiles = fs.readdirSync(pathToFile);

    return allFiles.map(file => pathToFile + "/" + file);

  }));

  allPaths = flatten(allPaths);

  Promise.all(
    allPaths.map(file => {
      return getFileAsObject(file).then(res => {
        return res;
      });
    })
  ).then(result)
}

readMotoBike(bikePaths, bikeTypes, result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: @ysytnik updated the code so that you can get your array of objects as a callback in `readMotoBike`